# C++: Using end of file (ctrl+z) to end a loop seems to break cin for the rest of my program

Tags: c++, while-loop, eof

The rest of the program still runs, but none of the cin's prompt the user for input.

```
double sales;
cout << "(Commision Employee) Please enter the employee's Sales: ";
while (cin >> sales) {
try
{
    employee1.setGrossSales(sales);
}
catch (invalid_argument& e)
{
    cout << "\nException: " << e.what() << "\n\n";
}
cout << "Please re-enter value if an error occured, otherwise enter end-of-file (ctrl+z): ";
}

string ssn;
cout << "(Base Plus Commision Employee) Please enter the SSN with dashes: ";
cin >> ssn;
employee2.setSocialSecurityNumber(ssn);
```

The cin following the loop doesn't function like I expected it too. What I gather is that cin has a boolean end-of-file marker that is switched to true upon receiving the end-of-file (ctrl+z on windows). It's this marker that prevents cin from operating again. I have found that I can use std::cin.clear(); to clear this marker.

I found this answer here which does a better job at both describing the same issue I had and answering it: [while (cin >> x) and end-of-file issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078218/while-cin-x-and-end-of-file-issues?rq=1)

For my purposes, this was all I needed.

Comment: Why would you expect `cin` to keep working after you told it the file had ended?

Comment: are you on  windows ?

Comment: Post a [MCVE], not a fragment.  What platform? Visual C++ maybe?

Comment: You already have a good exit. If the user types in anything that isn't a double, you're out of the loop. Smarten that up a bit  to clear the error flag, read the input as a string, test the string for "exit" and either exit or chuck the string and go back to looking for `double`s and you're good to go.

Comment: @Galik, I was unaware cin operated in this manner.

Comment: @Srini Yes, Windows 10.

Comment: @JiveDadson, I have added 4 lines to my code in the question. The cin >> ssn; doesn't prompt the user for input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while (cin >> x) and end-of-file issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078218/while-cin-x-and-end-of-file-issues)

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl+z` is actually `0x1A` byte that sets the `std::basic_ios::eof` to `true`, which means that associated stream has reached end-of-file.

[Windows system can not read beyond the 0x1A (EOF) character but Unix can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582804/why-can-windows-not-read-beyond-the-0x1a-eof-character-but-unix-can?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)